# Why does the Stream class implement IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net

Why does the Stream class implement IDisposable?
I think the Stream class itself doesn't have any unmanaged resources.
Certainly, some of the subclasses have unmanaged resources (e.g. FileStream), but not all of subclasses have unmanaged resources (e.g. MemoryStream).

If the answer to the above question is "because the subclasses of the Stream class may have unmanaged resources", then why doesn't the Object class implement IDisposable?

Comment: Quite hard to say really, we can assume, or suppose, or consider, but unless one of the library platform people answers, we cannot know. Most likely it is because when you pass a Stream object to a StreamReader (as an instance), and then later dispose of the StreamReader, the Stream will be disposed as well. Since most actual Stream implementations will in some way be related to a resource, I guess they just made it very clear from the start that this is what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

No one said the resources had to be unmanaged.  It has resources that need to be cleaned up.  You can accomplish the same thing with `Close()`, but the idea is that you can use it with a `using` statement, and then the resources will be guaranteed to be cleaned up, even in the case of an exception.

```
using (var s = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    //do something.
}
```